# If statement with value match

Tags: if-statement, pyautogui

I'm having a problem with if statement when checking if value matches.

The intention is to check for the resolution of the screen and then accordingly use predefined coordinates (with the relation to the resolution) to click with `pyautogui` so the script can be run on displays with different resolutions.

This is the code:

```
import pyautogui
screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size()
if (screenWidth == 1920, screenHeight == 1080):
    click1 = 780, 150
    click2 = 150, 120
    click3 = 450, 120
if (screenWidth == 1366, screenHeight == 768):
    click1 = 650, 120
    click2 = 120, 100
    click3 = 350, 100
if (screenWidth == 1360, screenHeight == 768):
    click1 = 650, 120
    click2 = 120, 100
    click3 = 350, 100
if (screenWidth == 1280, screenHeight == 800):
    click1 = 630, 110
    click2 = 120, 90
    click3 = 350, 90
if (screenWidth == 1280, screenHeight == 768):
    click1 = 630, 120
    click2 = 120, 90
    click3 = 350, 100

print(screenWidth,screenHeight)
print(click1,click2,click3)
```

and this is the output which is not what is given above for 1080p:

```
1920 1080
(630, 120) (120, 90) (350, 100)
```

Also the message "re-declared click1 defined above without usage" appears.
Is there something I'm missing with the code?

Comment: You might want to learn more about [the logical operations](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations) of Python.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

The solution is to first check if one condition is satisfied (resolution i y axis) and then the other (resolution in x axis)

```
import pyautogui
screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size()
if screenHeight == 1080:
    click1 = 780, 150
    click2 = 150, 120
    click3 = 450, 120
if screenHeight == 768:
    if screenWidth == 1366:
        click1 = 650, 120
        click2 = 120, 100
        click3 = 350, 100
    if screenWidth == 1360:
        click1 = 650, 120
        click2 = 120, 100
        click3 = 350, 100
    if screenWidth == 1280:
        click1 = 630, 120
        click2 = 120, 90
        click3 = 350, 100
    if screenWidth == 1024:
        click1 = 620, 120
        click2 = 120, 90
        click3 = 320, 100
if screenHeight == 800:
    click1 = 630, 110
    click2 = 120, 90
    click3 = 350, 90
```